# Question relating to joint PDFs

Tags: probability, distributions, variance, expected-value, covariance-matrix

Here are my questions:

1. Let $X$ ~ Unif$(0, 1)$, and $0<a<b<1$. Also, let
   \begin{cases}
                                  Y =    1 & \text{if $0<X<b$} \\
                                   Y =   0 & \text{otherwise} \\
     \end{cases}

Similarly, let
\begin{cases}
                                 Z =    1 & \text{if $a<X<1$} \\
                                 Z =   0 & \text{otherwise} \\
  \end{cases}

Find the variance-covariance matrix of Y, Z.

What I tried: Note that P($0<X<b$) = $F_X(b)$ - $F_X(0)$ = $\frac{x}{b}$.

Similarly, note P($a<X<1$) = $F_X(1)$ - $F_X(0)$ = $\frac{x-a}{x-b}$.

Then, $E(Y)$ = $1*P($0<X<b$)$ + $0*[$1$-P($0<X<b$)]$ = $\frac{x}{b}$.
Similarly, E(Z) = $\frac{x-a}{1-a}$. Here, I get stuck (and I don't even know if it's right).

Comment: There are two not-so-short questions here. Please ask (2) in a separate thread.

Comment: Where specifically are you having a problem? I'm not really sure on this one.

Comment: I removed #2. In #1, I'm just having trouble finding the expectations themselves. I don't think I'm doing it right because the expectations have values of X = x in them. I haven't taken expectations of piecewise functions of RVs before so I'm just having trouble conceptualizing how to find Var(Y) and Var(Z) (But I need E(Y) and E(Z) first). With some hints on how to do so, I should be able to calculate the variance-covariance matrix.

Comment: @BoJack does the answer help you in any way?

Comment: @gunes Yes, it does. But can you explain why P(0 < X < b) = b? I figured that, for X ~ U(0,1), P(0 < X < b) = F(b) - F(0) but I don't see how this equates to b. Similar with P(a < X < 1).

Comment: Uniform RV has CDF $F(x)=x$ for $0\leq x\leq 1$, so $F(b)=b$ and $F(0)=0$. Also note that $F(x)=1$ for $x\geq 1$ and $F(x)=0$ for $x\leq 0$.

Comment: Ah, that makes perfect sense, thank you! With this information, I get that E(Y) = b, E(Z) = 1 - a, Var(Y) = E(Y^2) - [E(Y)]^2 = b - b^2, Var(Z) = E(Z^2) - [E(Z)]^2 = a - a^2, and Cov(ZY) = Cov(YZ) = E(ZY) - E(Z)*E(Y) = (b - a) - (1-a)*b. Do these answers look correct to you?

Comment: They *seem* correct.

Comment: Awesome, thank you for all of your help!

Comment: Sounds good. I've done so!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, $P(0<X<b)=b$ not $x/b$, i.e. not a function of $x$. Similarly, $P(a<X<1)=1-a$. These are also equal to $E[Y],E[Z]$ respectively. Also, we have $E[Y^2]=E[Y],E[Z^2]=E[Z]$ for binary RV case. For the joint moment, $E[YZ]=P(Y=1\cap Z=1)=P(a<X<b)=b-a$. I think you can follow from here.